# How to move camera around object to look at object from all sides?

Tags: camera, cesiumjs

How can a cesium camera be moved around an object in circular path?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want something similar to helicopter circles... It can be done by 'lookAt' at every clock tick.

```js
let heading = 0; //or any starting angle in radians
let rotation = -1; //counter-clockwise; +1 would be clockwise
let centre = new Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(longitude, latitude);
let elevation = 100; // 100 meters
let pitch = -0.7854; //looking down at 45 degrees

const SMOOTHNESS = 600; //it would make one full circle in roughly 600 frames

viewer.clock.onTick.addEventListener(() => {
    heading += rotation * Math.PI / SMOOTHNESS;
    viewer.camera.lookAt(centre, new Cesium.HeadingPitchRange(heading, pitch, elevation));
});
```